# Groovy: create a two-dimensional array from two ranges

Tags: groovy, range

I want to create this:

```
[ [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 2 ], [ 1, 3 ], [ 2, 1 ] ... [ 6, 3 ]]
```

Using GroovyConsole I've being trying stuff like this:

```
def blob = (1..6).collect{ i ->
  (1..3).collect{ j ->
    [ i, j ]
  }
}
println "$blob ${blob.class.simpleName}"
```

... with various permutations of calls to `flatten`, as you might surmise.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier to do using the `combinations` method:

```
l1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
l2 = [1,2,3]
[l, l2].combinations()
```

Which outputs:

```
[[1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 1], [4, 1], [5, 1], [6, 1], [1, 2], [2, 2], 
 [3, 2], [4, 2], [5, 2], [6, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3], [3, 3], [4, 3], 
 [5, 3], [6, 3]]
```

Comment: Wonderful! Wonderful! (I had to say it twice before it would let me post.  Not knowing your mother tongue, I hesitated before guessing).

Comment: `[1..6, 1..3].combinations()` should do it with ranges