# How to change the "data provider" returned from a closure into a "data provider"?

Tags: groovy, closures, spock, iterable, data-driven-tests

This is in the context of "data driven" testing with Spock:

```
where:
key << myDriver.myMap.keySet()
```

... works fine: the key values are delivered, the parameterised testing works.

But if I try this:

```
where:
key << { myDriver.myMap.keySet() }
```

it doesn't work. The object then on the RHS of the `<<` is a `Closure`. I've then tried numerous things to try to coax a "data provider" out of this `Closure`.

I want to put a closure there firstly so that I can debug a bit but also to provide a more complex set of permutations (not just of "key" values but values of other test parameters... see a recent question of mine [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50192237/groovy-create-a-two-dimensional-array-from-two-ranges)).

Perhaps it's not helped by the class delivered by `keySet()`: turns out this is a `LinkedHashMap$LinkedKeySet`... but it's obviously `Iterable`.

I'm a little bit mystified by this "data provider" category. In the Spock "tutorial" it says that this must implement `Iterable`. It doesn't say whether that's all its characteristics. Going

```
{ myDriver.myMap.keySet() }.iterator()
```

doesn't help... `iterator()` obviously delivers `Iterator`, not `Iterable` anyway. What I then get is horrors like this:

> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:
>   core.MyModule.processCommand() is applicable for argument types:
>   (core.UT_ForMyModule$__spock_feature_1_12prov0_closure8,
>   joptsimple.OptionSet, java.util.ArrayList) values:
>   [core.UT_ForMyModule$__spock_feature_1_12prov0_closure8@65fdd86b, ...]

... which clearly means it's delivering an `Iterator` which iterates over a `Collection` of precisely one `Closure`.

So, in short, how do I get an `Iterable` from a closure returning an `Iterable`?

Comment: @DaveNewton You edited out the beginning of my title, "Groovy: ...".  I think I understand why you did that... but obviously Groovy closures don't necessarily function like closures from another language.  Wouldn't it at least be reasonable to edit to say "from a Groovy closure" in the title?

Comment: @ErnestKiwele Thanks, just tried that (wasn't aware of Closure.run because it's not showing in the GDK GroovyDoc, although it does in the "gapi" GroovyDoc, I find...).  Unfortunately this gives "org.spockframework.runtime.SpockExecutionException: Data provider is null!"

Comment: Shrug. Titles shouldn't have tags, that's what the tags are for. You *could*, but it's redundant. https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging

Comment: @DaveNewton I bow to your superior rep-ness.

Comment: Bowing to the FAQ/docs is better ;) But I'll take it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have delayed execution objectives here, I believe just running the closure should do:

```
key << { myDriver.myMap.keySet() }()
```

But note that this will execute it in the statement.

Comment: Thanks... that's twice today.  I had no idea of this concept of "running" a `Closure`... as I said in my comment above, I've just discovered `Closure` has a `run` method (not shown in the GDK GroovyDoc, for reasons I may one day understand...)

Comment: Good to know it works... Groovy has a lot of useful tricks that don't naturally occur to us (all of us).

Comment: @mikerodent http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/Closure.html#run--